# Eigenspace and Eigenvalue product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the vector space, $V$ of the upper triangular matrices order $2\times2,$ consider the operator  $T : V \to V$
such that

$T\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 4a+2b & 3b-a \\ 0 & b+2c \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. Knowing that $T$ has eigenspace in the $z$ axis and the line $[(-2y, y, y)/y] \in \mathscr R$ which is the product eigenvalues associated to those space .

So I'm having trouble understanding the last part

> $z$ axis and the line $[(-2y, y, y)/y]$